# Variable declearation and option explicit in vba excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote some vba codes in excel 2010, it works fine in excel 2010, but now I have excel 2013 on my laptop and whenever I run my code, it gave me "Compile Error; Can't find project or Library" error and highlight the first undeclared variable!
then if I declare variable, everything would be ok on that procedure; but I have too much codes and have no time to declare all the variables in it.
there is no option explicit in my code and "require variable declaration" in editor option is unchecked.
what should I do?

Comment: Dear @Jeeped ,
as I mentioned before, it's unchecked already.

Comment: The error code you are receiving seems to indicate a change in library version rather than variable declaration. What are the differences in the Tools ► References listbox between the 2010 VBE and the 2013 VBE?

Comment: Thanks
yes, you are right; one of the references was missing and by removing it everything works fine